# How do I remove a folder stuck in my GitHub portal?

Tags: git

I have been having a problem with a folder that shows in my GitHub desktop portal, but not in my GitHub repo page. Whenever I need to push commit to that repo, I have to uncheck the phantom folder or my changes do not commit.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the repo in question:]

[image: And here is the same repo as seen in my desktop portal]

Notice that the folder "PProject-1" (misspelled with 2 p's) exists on the portal but not the web page. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: sidenote: is the desktop application really called "Portal" these days? terrifying :-(

Comment: What happens when you try to make a commit while "PProject-1" is checked?

Comment: Is "PProject-1" an empty folder in your local copy of the repository? Can you simply delete it?

Comment: mkreiger: If I try to make a commit while "PProject-1" is checked, I get an error message that says not everything committed, and when I check my repo on the website, there is no commit there. I bring up my command prompt, cd to the local copy of this repo, and the dir lists "Project-1" but not "PProject-1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first "P" in "PProject-1" is grayed out, indicating that it is not part of the file name. In your comment, you noted that your local (cloned) repo has a folder called "Project-1," that does not exist in your remote (GitHub website) repo. Move that folder out of the local repo, and it should disappear from the queue in your app also.